# How to create a cred.json file using gcloud auth login?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Can we create credentials.json file using gcloud auth login? Requirement is -  user should use personal  account in the minikube and use cred.json file as a secret in their cluster.
Current setup - For QA we have a service account key which get mounted on the gke cluster as secret.

Comment: Hello, I saw the comment you made under one of the answers but I'm still confused about the setup you are trying to achieve. Do I understand correctly that you want to get the credentials from `GCP` to be fetched and then used in a secret. Does the pod on minikube needs this credentials from GCP to ran the legacy software of yours?

Comment: @Dawid - your understanding is correct. Currently service account key is mounted as secret in pod. Requirement is - Instead of service account key, can each User create  credentials key similar to service key and mount it as secret.

Comment: @Dawid - idea is No developer should have access to service account key.

Answer (score 2):

To access to google cloud API, you need an OAuth2 access_token and you can generate it with user credential (and after a `gcloud auth login`)

So, you can call [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create) or directly [the API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create) with an access token in parameter

*Example with curl*

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"
```

**EDIT**

As explained before, a user credential created with `gcloud auth login` can only, today, create an access_token.

Access token are required to access to Google API (included Google Cloud products). If it's your use case, you can use it.

However, if you need an id_token, for example to access to private Cloud Functions, private Cloud Run, App Engine behind IAP, you can't (not directly, I have a fix for this if you want).

Comment: Thanks, My requirement is different. We have a legacy code base where service key json is mounted as secret and consumed by pod. I wanted to know if I as a  developer does have a service key, can I use "gcloud auth login" and generate the credential json and use it as a secret in my minikube setup for development purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the principle of least privilege, **each developer should have his own dedicated `GCP Service Account`**:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Blog: Identity security: Don't get pwned practicing the principle of least privilege](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/dont-get-pwned-practicing-the-principle-of-least-privilege)*

Account created like that should have assigned only the **necessary** [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

You can generate a key for this account with a following command:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
--iam-account=${DEVELOPER_USERNAME}
```

> `key.json` <-- is a file name and can be changed (example: `username-access-token.json`)

More reference can be found in the official documentation:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Gcloud: IAM: Service-accounts: Keys: Create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create)*

With above key you can communicate with `GCP API`'s. You will need a `Secret` mounted to a `Pod` with this access token as well as an `env` variable in a `Pod` like one below:

- `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PATH_TO_MOUNTED_SECRET_WITH_ACCESS_TOKEN}`

By following this way, a developer could "see" the access token from a `Secret` but won't be able to do anything besides what the role bindings to his gcp service account allows him to do.

---

You can also have unified process of creating such user accounts. One of the tools that would allow it is [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/). You can read more about the modules that will create such accounts and keys here:

- *[Terraform.io: Google: Google service account](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account.html)*
- *[Terraform.io: Google: Google service account key](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/google_service_account_key.html)*